# How to parse HTML without calling the direct parent

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I want to parse this HTML using jsoup but I need to extract the headline and subtitle without using the class "Changing class name" because the class name always changing. I need the text just from the "h1" attribute and the "p"

The Html:

```
<header class="my header">
   <div class="row">
      <h3>I don't want this      </h3>
      <div class="Changing class name">
         <h1>The headline             </h1>
         <p class=" my subtitle">
            The subtitle
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I don't know JSoup that well but if you don't want to use that class you'll probably have to make sure the structure is always the same and then access the elements via theirs paths, i.e. `header.div.div.h1` and `header.div.div.p` (and if there are multiple divs you'll probably need a constant index as well).

Answer (score 1):

We can used the getElementsByTag in this way:

```
String MyTitle = doc.getElementsByTag("h1").get(0).text();
```

Or we can used the select in this way (work faster):

```
String MyTitle = doc.select("my.header h1").first().text().trim();
```

Regarding the subtitle I added a check to avoid entering a NULL to a string:

```
Element Subtitle = doc.select("p.my").first();
if (Subtitle != null) {
    String MySubtitle = doc.select("p.my").text().trim();}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would comment but I can't yet

I know that there is a function `getElementsByTag()` which you can use to get every Element of `<h1>`, so if you know only the headline is using `<h1>` you can use this one

You can as well use `select()` (https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) to select the headline or for example the subtitle
You didn't say that the class of the subtitle changes so I assume you can query for a `<p>` tag of class my subtitle

Comment: Thanks. Working partly fine. I forgot to mention but sometimes there are articles without a subtitle so when I am doing 
String articleSubTitle = doc.getElementsByTag("p").get(0).text(); and there isn't "p" I get exception

Comment: Well you can check if the list or whatever you get back from getElementsByTag() has a size bigger than 0 and based on this get(0) or not
I dont know I don't really like this whole site parsing thing, it feels so static and wrong xD

Comment: Yes. Its return NULL so I added a check before saving it in a String